# Anaconda Zipline Installation Error

Tags: python, anaconda, zipline

I've been trying to install Quantopian zipline (http://www.zipline.io/) python package through Anaconda, but have not been able to. When I run either of the lines below

> conda install -c Quantopian zipline
>
> conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/Quantopian zipline

in the Anaconda prompt, I get a short pause and the message

> Fetching package metadata...
>   Solving package specification..
>
> Error: package missing in current win-64 channels:
>
> -zipline

However, if I run the search command "anaconda search -t conda zipline" I can see that Quantopian/zipline has a win-64 compatible package.

I have a 64-bit Windows 8.1 with conda ver 4.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the latest zipline has been build in their channel.

the same error happened to one of my colleagues with the last version of zipline (1.1.0) and mac OsX. 
We figured out that the guys at Quantopian didn't publish a build for that OS.

Workaround:

1 - try to install zipline via pip (as they say in the guidelines)
or
2 - Download the source code ad build it by yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

These are the Requirements/ Steps to Make Zipline Work:

1. Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express
2. Download and install python 3.4
3. Download zipline from github and Extract in C:/
4. Set Anaconda as project interpreter
5. Since zipline is compatible with Python 3.4, you need to create an environment with Python 3.4
6. Run this command in console of IDE:
   `$conda create -n python34 python=3.4 anaconda`(replace py34 with the location of python34 folder)
7. Now run this command in console:
   `$activate python34` #Activates the python 3.4 environment
8. `$pip install -e C:\GitHub\zipline` (Directory where you extracted zipline)
9. Ingest data from quandl with below command
   `$zipline ingest`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Zipline-Trader version was released. For stable version `pip install zipline-trader` For more info follow [docs](https://zipline-trader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for installation.